# Python save output line into new file

Tags: python

I get some lines (a record) from log file, but I didn't know how to write function inside it to create a new log file whose name contains the current date in which to store those lines. I'm new python, so I hope you can give me solution. Thanks

```
 def OnlyRecent(line):
    if  time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")> time.gmtime(time.time()-(60*60*24*7)):
        return True
    return False
  for line in f:
    if OnlyRecent(line):
       print line  //store print lines into new log file.  20120911.log
```

Comment: Which part are you having problems with?

Comment: checkout python file I/O operation: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: check this out: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect print output to a file:

```
log_file = open('mylog.log', 'w')

print>>log_file, 'hello'

log_file.close()
```

Comment: This works in Python 2.x, but it might be good to show the corresponding `print()` call for 3.x as well.

Answer (score 1):

outside your loop

```
filename = time.strftime('%Y%m%d') + '.log'
f = open(filename, 'w')
```

do your loop here, and write each line with

```
f.write(line)
```

if you don't have a new line character in your line variable, do

```
f.write(line +'\n')
```

after exiting your loop

```
f.close()
```